# Example-Swift.h not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm developing an iOS framework that mixes Objective C and Swift code. Build fails at the `#import "Example-Swift.h"` line with `'Example-Swift.h' file not found`.

The header file does get generated, I can find it at:

`DerivedData/Example/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Example.framework/Headers/Example-Swift.h`

I tried all of the upvoted solutions on Stack Overflow, none worked. The only fix is manually adding the directory to `User Header Search Paths` in build settings.

I must be doing something wrong though if other people don't have to manually add the header path. Also, when users of this framework include it as a pod, they need to do update the build settings as well, which I really want to avoid.

So, is there a solution to this that's not an ugly hack? I'm using XCode 9.0.1. I wish Xcode / iOS had a normal build system... coming from Linux/Android, I like many things about the iOS ecosystem but the build system is just ridiculous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this problem in a mixed Objective-C/Swift framework and my solution was to include the module name as the directory part of the include.  In your case it would be

```
#import "Example/Example-Swift.h"
```

instead of

```
#import "Example-Swift.h"
```

This is actually documented in the *Importing Swift into Objective-C* subsection of *Importing Code from Within the Same Framework Target* at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html